# React-Native-Testing-Library 'warning - an updated was not wrapped in act(...)

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, testing, react-native-testing-library, act

I think this question has been asked, but no solution was provided.

I'm using RNTL trying to unit test a simple RN component.

My example below:

```
    component = render(<ThemeProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <LandingScreen />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </ThemeProvider>
    );
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
  });


it('renders the main title correcty', async () => {
    const { findByText } = component;
    const heading = await waitFor(() => findByText('Bringing Banking into the Future'));
    expect(heading).toBeTruthy()
  })
```

I've tried many different waits of using this, without the `await waitFor()` and I keep getting the same error (see below)

```
      
      When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
      
      act(() => {
        /* fire events that update state */
      });
      /* assert on the output */
```

I've also tried all the things mentioned here: https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/379#issuecomment-714341282, including replacing the `findBy`with a `getBy` no luck.

Any ideas would be welcome!

thanks